# how to clear session when the user leaves my site

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to clear my session when the user leave my site.
when i try to do like below using 'beforeunload' event, even when i try to give enter on my site/application url also my handleBeforeUnload is getting called. Ideally i want to clear if the url(host/origin) is entered is different from my site then only i want to clear my session.

how to escape calling handleBeforeUnload - if the user enter my site specific urls ? or any other possible solution to achieve this request would be appreciated.

Below code i tried with my  app.js

```
const getAppOrigin = window.location.origin;
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    };
}, [getAppOrigin]);

const handleBeforeUnload = ev => {
    if (ev || window.event) {
        // clear sessions code here
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you try [sesionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)?

Comment: hi, i already have few sessionStorage, i want to clear all only when the user leave my site

Comment: What do you mean `leave the website`? close the tab of the browser or logout of the page?

Comment: @ikhavjs: i) close the tab and ii) when the user enter differ url on my current tab and give enter to load differ url

Comment: You may then store the session in the js memory only. Once you enter different url in the current tab/close the tab, the js memory would be erased. You may store the session in [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).